# Routes not working properly

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the below code when I try to hit the "/hello" route using the get method I am getting the following response. All the other routes are working fine except the "/hello" route using get method. Why is this happening?

[image]

```
var http = require('http');
var url  = require('url');
var stringDecoder = require('string_decoder').StringDecoder;

var server = http.createServer(function(req,res){
    //parse the URL and get the path if we pass true as paramater it will act as query string
    var parsedURL = url.parse(req.url,true);

    //Get the path alone
    var path = parsedURL.pathname;

    //Trimm the URL
    var trimmedpath = path.replace(/^\/+|\/+$/g,'');

    //Get the method
    var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

    //Get the headers
    var headers = req.headers;      

    //get the querystring as an object
    var queryStringObject = parsedURL.query;

    //Get the payload if any
    var decoder = new stringDecoder('utf-8');
    var buffer = '';

    req.on('data',function(data){
        buffer += decoder.write(data);
    });

    req.on('end',function(){
        buffer += decoder.end();

        //Generate the data
        var data = {
            'method' : method,
            'headers' : headers,
            'trimmedpath' : trimmedpath,
            'queryStringObject' : queryStringObject
        }

        var Handler = routes[trimmedpath];

        var chosenHandler = typeof(Handler) !== 'undefined' ? Handler : handlers.notfound;

        chosenHandler(data,function(statuscode,payload){

            statuscode = typeof(statuscode) == 'number' ? statuscode : 300;
            payload   = typeof(payload) == 'object' ? payload : {};

            console.log(payload);

            var payloadString = JSON.stringify(payload);

            //set the content type to view as object
            res.setHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
            res.writeHead(statuscode);
            res.end(payloadString);

        });

        //Sending the response
        console.log(buffer);
        console.log(Handler,chosenHandler);
        res.end("hello world");
    });

});

var handlers = {};

handlers.hello = function(data,callback){
    if(data.method == 'post'){
        callback(404,{'Message' : 'You have hitted the post route'});
    }
    if(data.method == 'get'){
        callback(143,{'message':  'you have hitted the get route'});
    }
}

handlers.ping = function(data,callback){
    callback(999,{'message':'ping route'});
}

handlers.notfound = function(data,callback){
    callback(600,{'Message' : 'Major issue'});
}

var routes = {
    'ping'  : handlers.ping,
    'hello' : handlers.hello
}
server.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server started listening in the port 3000");
});
```

I have split the messages based on the method received from the request.

Comment: What happens when on your hello handler, you `console.log(data.method)` when you send hello (outside of the ifs)

Comment: HTTP methods are in capital, while you are comparing it with small 'get', 'post'

Comment: Always include error messages **as text**, not just as pictures. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: I have converted the method to lowercase before passing it to the routes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're comparing HTTP method in small

```
 handlers.hello = function(data,callback){
if(data.method === 'POST'){
    callback(404,{'Message' : 'You have hitted the post route'});
}
if(data.method === 'GET'){
    callback(143,{'message':  'you have hitted the get route'});
}
}
```

I'll suggest you to use some already built router to handle multiple cases without increasing code length.

**Update**

considering you're already lower casing http method, I can see hello is being called without modifying your code;

```
{ message: 'you have hitted the get route' }

[Function] [Function]

{ Message: 'You have hitted the post route' }

[Function] [Function]
```

And the response in POSTMAN.

[image]

Comment: I have converted the method to lowercase before sending it to the handlers.

Comment: //Get the method
    var method = req.method.toLowerCase();

Comment: Then you should not see any issue. I've updated the answer with console log without modifying your code.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Even i could ge the console like mentioned above. But i am not getting any respose back while trying it in postman with the get method.

Comment: It is throwing unable to get response(please refer the attched screenshot)

Comment: Don't use string decoder. Use Buffer instead and concatenate it in last. onData `chunks.push(chunk);` onFinish `chunks = Buffer.concat(chunks);`

Comment: Thanks for the update Amit. I am also getting the same output as you have mentioned while using the POST method. But the problem here is with the GET method. If i use the get method i couldn't get any response.

Comment: Sorry i have mentioned anything wrongly. I am new to NODE.js. I would like to understand why the "GET" method in the "/hello" route is not working as i have handled the both using the if statements.

Comment: @ajithkumar even "get" is returning response code 143 as you mentioned in the code. I can't find any issue with the code.